# WebSocket in Plain Java

Tags: java, http, networking, websocket, webserver

I am coding a Web Framework for me with an WebServer and an WebSocket Server.

My Current Problem since days is, that the Response Content of my WebSocket Client is very funny...

It sends me not the Content as bytes, every time the value is another.

Web Response for normal HTTP and the Socket request works perfectly.

My current Code:

```
                            poolIO.execute(new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    InputStream inputIO = clientIO.getInputStream();
                                    StringBuilder builderIO = new StringBuilder();

                                    while (clientIO.isConnected()) {

                                        int cacheIO = 0;
                                        int countIO = 0;
                                        byte[] binaryIO = new byte[0];


                                        while ((inputIO.available() != 0 && (cacheIO = inputIO.read()) != 0)) {
                                            binaryIO = new byte[binaryIO.length + 1];
                                            binaryIO[countIO] = (byte) cacheIO;
                                            builderIO.append((char) cacheIO);
                                            countIO++;
                                        }


                                        if (builderIO.length() > 0) {
                                            string(clientIO, builderIO.toString());
                                            binary(clientIO, binaryIO);
                                            binaryIO = new byte[0];
                                            builderIO.delete(0, builderIO.length());
                                        }
                                    }

                                    inputIO.close();

                                    disconnect(clientIO);

                                    this.stop();
                                } catch (IOException errorIO) {
                                    if (errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Stream closed.")) {
                                        logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.INFO, "Client with IP " + clientIO.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " disconnected from Server with Port " + networkIO.getPort() + ".");
                                    } else logIO.append(GuardianLog.Type.ERROR, "Socket throw an Error ", errorIO);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Regards
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed getting raw bytes with following Code:

```
      byte[] bufferIO = new byte[inputIO.available()];

                                inputIO.read(bufferIO);

                                if (bufferIO.length != 0) {
                                    binary(clientIO, bufferIO);
                                    string(clientIO, new String(bufferIO));
                                }
```